# Getting the URL from FirebaseStorage URI in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-web

Sorry for the noob question. But how do I get the Url String from a Uri ? In my understanding the Url is a subset of Uri but I couldn't find any method that says something like `.getUrl`. Did I miss anything ?

Background:
The `getDownloadURL()` of FirebaseStorage in Flutter Web somehow returns `Uri` instead of `String`.

The explanation from from Flutter Web's FirebaseStorage package:

> Future<Uri> getDownloadURL() package:firebase/src/storage.dart
>
> Returns a long lived download URL for this reference.

The `getDownloadURL` explanation from from **Flutter App's** FirebaseStorage package:

> Future<String> getDownloadURL()
> package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart
>
> Fetches a long lived download URL for this object.

In the Flutter App my pubspec.yaml:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.2
  firebase_storage: ^5.0.0-dev.4
```

In the Flutter Web my pubspec.yaml:

```
  firebase: ^7.3.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.2
  cloud_functions: ^0.6.0+1
```

I tried to find solutions and read the docs but I haven't found any writing about converting the Uri to Url from Firebase Storage `getDownloadURL` method. It seems to be treated almost like the same thing. But it gave me error. See Code below:

*** Code:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(String localFilename, String filename, String path, StorageReference ref) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/posts_images/$localFilename');
    final bytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    final metadata = UploadMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg');
    final uploadTask = ref.child('$path/$filename').put(bytes, metadata); 
    final snapshot = await uploadTask.future;
    final url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return url; // Error: A value of type 'Uri' can't be returned from method 'uploadImage' because it has a return type of 'Future<String>' 
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have added the code above. And this is only in Flutter Web. In Flutter App this doesn't happen.

Comment: But my question is how to convert the URI to URL and possibly to get answer on how to get the URL from the Firebase Storage methods in Flutter Web

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [Uri](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/Uri-class.html) class has a method [toString()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/Uri/toString.html).

```
return url.toString();
```

Comment: Oh it is that simple. I didn't realize it, I thought the `.toString` would just return something like `A Uri Object` or something else. Didn't realize it actually turns it into Url. Thanks Doug. Sorry for the noob question again..

Comment: LOL, never expected this to work, but it does. Thanks!